# Get Out Of Memory

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

This is my refresh chart's data's code:

```
public void showLineChart(final List<String> xAxisValues, final List<List<String>> yAxisValues,
                              final List<String> labels, List<Integer> colours) {
        lineChart.resetTracking();
        final List<String> xa = new ArrayList<>(xAxisValues);
        markerView.setCallBack(new CustomMarkerView.CallBack() {
            @Override
            public void onCallBack(float x, String value) {
                int index = (int) (x);
                if (index < 0) {
                    return;
                }
                String textTemp = "";
                if (yAxisValues.size() > 1) {
                    textTemp = "室外：" + yAxisValues.get(1).get(index);
                    markerView.getTextViewOutdoor().setText(textTemp);
                    markerView.getLl().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                textTemp = "室内：" + yAxisValues.get(0).get(index);
                markerView.getTextViewIndoor().setText(textTemp);
                markerView.getTextViewDate().setText(xa.get(index));
                markerView.setAlpha((float) 0.7);
            }
        });

        MyCustomXAxisValueFormatter formatter = new MyCustomXAxisValueFormatter(xAxisValues);
        xAxis.setValueFormatter(formatter);
        List<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < yAxisValues.size(); i++) {
            List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
            List<String> values=new ArrayList<>(yAxisValues.get(i));
            if(values.size()>0){
                for (int j = 0; j < values.size(); j++) {
                    if (j >= xAxisValues.size()) {
                        j = xAxisValues.size() - 1;
                    }
                    if (j>-1&&values.get(j)!=null){
                        entries.add(new Entry(j, Float.parseFloat(values.get(j))));
                    }
                }
                if (i<labels.size()){
                    LineDataSet lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(entries, labels.get(i)); 
                    initLineDataSet(lineDataSet, colours.get(i), false);
                    dataSets.add(lineDataSet);
                }
            }
        }
        LineData data = new LineData(dataSets);
        xAxis.setLabelCount(xAxisValues.size(), true);
        lineChart.setData(data);
        lineChart.invalidate();
    }
```

I have read the demo of Github, but that can't solve the problem:
There are so many error in my console like this:

> I/zygote64: Background concurrent copying GC freed 661970(20MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 57% free, 8MB/20MB, paused 855us total 101.178ms

It will crash after a period of time with the OOM error.
Who can help me?

Comment: The problem is prolly not with this code but rather with size of the Lists and frequency of refreshing

Comment: @Selvin I set it to refresh every 60s, and the length of list is 18

Answer (score 1):

> There are so many error in my console like this:
>
> I/zygote64: Background concurrent copying GC freed 661970(20MB)
>   AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 57% free, 8MB/20MB, paused
>   855us total 101.178ms

This is not an error, this just gives you information of allocating/freeing new memory for your application. This happens when allocating large amount of memory or when memory becomes freed because there are no more references to it.

When this message comes to often, this may indicate a bad memory handling in your app.

> It will crash after a period of time with the OOM error.

This means that your applciation went out of memory. This happens when you try to allocate memory which is not available on your device (or not provided by the JVM).

What you should do now is find out where this large amount of memory is allocated and if there are other options to reduce memory usage. Some simple approaches could be:

- use global (static) variables only where necessary
- free resources as soon you do not need them anymore (e.g. recycle bitmaps)
- check your code if you can optimize it to use less resources. Sometimes it happens that for example the same data is inside two different arrays.
- if all that does not help, you could try to increase your heap size by setting `android:largeHeap="true"` in your AndroidManifest. But this should be only considered as a last step. Keep in mind that the different devices and android versions provide different amount of memory to your application.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know that this is the problem of memory leak. I just want to make sure whether it is the third-party library of this chart or my operation